# Python - Using column headings as keys for dictionary from csv file (without import module)

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I must perform some calculations with values provided from a .csv file, and need to use the  column headings as keys to their values in each column. However there is a likelihood that the columns of the file may be jumbled up or swapped around, and thus simply indexing for the values of each key wouldn't work. Also keeping in mind i cant import any modules such as csv.
Heres a sample of what the csv file would look like, except with many more rows, and more AdultIDs...

| AdultID | Landmark | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R7033 | Ex_L | -32 | -39 | -4.6 |
| R7033 | En_L | -1.8 | -41 | 6.7 |
| R7033 | N | 12 | -34 | 22.6 |
| R7033 | En_R | 30.1 | -43 | 8.3 |

So effectively, I need the dictionary as such:
{AdultID: [R7033, R7033, R7033], Landmark:[Ex_L, En_R, N, En_R] ... } and so on.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use the csv module?

Comment: What did you try to do this _yourself_? What is the problem with _your_ code? [mre]? [ask]?

Comment: Open the file. Read the first line and split it on the column delimiter. That gives you your list of headings. Read subsequent lines (splitting as before) and make appropriate assignments to your dictionary

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Answered, read the file and create a dataframe at the bottom. Main at the top.

Comment: @inquirer OP wants a dictionary - not a dataframe. OP is not allowed to import *csv* module and therefore unlikely to be allowed to import *pandas*

Comment: Am I the only one who gets the feeling that the question is being shuffled?
At the same time, he hung for five hours, without moving. It was worth writing here and immediately everything stirred)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your input file (let's call it luh.csv) is a well formed CSV using commas as delimiters like this:

```
AdultID,Landmark,X,Y,Z
R7033,Ex_L,-32,-39,-4.6
R7033,En_L,-1.8,-41,6.7
R7033,N,12,-34,22.6
R7033,En_R,30.1,-43,8.3
```

Then:

```
with open('luh.csv') as csv:
    columns = next(csv).strip().split(',')
    dict_ = {}
    for line in map(str.strip, csv):
        for col, val in zip(columns, line.split(',')):
            dict_.setdefault(col, []).append(val)
    print(dict_)
```

**Output:**

```
{'AdultID': ['R7033', 'R7033', 'R7033', 'R7033'], 'Landmark': ['Ex_L', 'En_L', 'N', 'En_R'], 'X': ['-32', '-1.8', '12', '30.1'], 'Y': ['-39', '-41', '-34', '-43'], 'Z': ['-4.6', '6.7', '22.6', '8.3']}
```